# Why are not the hr tag elements going full width in the list?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

Why are my hr tag elements below in this table I made not of equal full width to go like the above line across the list? I have been trying to figure out but I cannot, I have been changing the width property but that does not help as well. Can someone give some advice or guidance on how to approach this?

```css
  #thing {
            border-style: solid;
            width: 50%;
        }
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid bg-white py-4">
        <div class="container">


            <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="thing" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">

                <p>

                </p>
                <hr>
                <ol>
                    <li>

                    </li>
                    <p>
                    </p>
                    <hr>
                    <li>

                    </li>
                    <p>
                    </p>
                    <hr>
                    <li>

                    </li>
                    <p>

                    </p>
                    <hr>

                </ol>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Because elements directly under ol and ul tags, has a padding inline start of 40px. Also hr tags (and p tags) are not a child element of a ol and ul tag, but li tags are.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways for this, I am giving you a lead here

1. Need to adjust left here with some px
   (Though you can replace below commented code into hr:before for exact HR width in div
   //left:10px
   // width: 48%
   )

   ```css
    #thing {
               border-style: solid;
               width: 50%;
           }
   hr:before {
         content: "";
       display: block;
       position: absolute;
       left: 0;        
       width: 50%;      
       border: 1px solid gainsboro;
   }
   hr {
     border:none;
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <div class="container-fluid bg-white py-4">
           <div class="container">


               <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="thing" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">

                   <p>

                   </p>
                   <hr>
                   <ol>
                       <li>

                       </li>
                       <p>
                       </p>
                       <hr>
                       <li>

                       </li>
                       <p>
                       </p>
                       <hr>
                       <li>

                       </li>
                       <p>

                       </p>
                       <hr>

                   </ol>

               </div>

           </div>
       </div>
   ```
2. worst: to set margin-left:-40px on hr property.